# Azure Search Microsoft English Search Analyzer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use the Microsoft English analyzer on a description field for autopart products. I encountered some unexpected behaviors with decimal measurement values so I ran it through the analyze API to confirm and it looks like the lemmatization algorithm is using the decimal point as a signal/delimeter to break the integer and decimal values as two separate tokens which I don't think that it's a desired behavior.

For example.

Text: "M12-1.50 Wheel Bolt - 14mm.  Hex, 23.12mm.  Thread Length 14mm.

Is broken up as

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://site.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2017_11_11.AnalyzeResult",
"tokens": [
 {
    "token": "m12-1",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 5,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "m12",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 3,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "1",
    "startOffset": 4,
    "endOffset": 5,
    "position": 1
    },
    {
    "token": "nn1",
    "startOffset": 4,
    "endOffset": 5,
    "position": 1
    },
    {
    "token": "50",
    "startOffset": 6,
    "endOffset": 8,
    "position": 2
    },
    {
    "token": "nn50",
    "startOffset": 6,
    "endOffset": 8,
    "position": 2
    },
    {
    "token": "wheel",
    "startOffset": 9,
    "endOffset": 14,
    "position": 3
    },
    {
    "token": "bolt",
    "startOffset": 15,
    "endOffset": 19,
    "position": 4
    },
    {
    "token": "14mm",
    "startOffset": 22,
    "endOffset": 26,
    "position": 5
    },
    {
    "token": "hex",
    "startOffset": 29,
    "endOffset": 32,
    "position": 6
    },
    {
    "token": "23",
    "startOffset": 34,
    "endOffset": 36,
    "position": 7
    },
    {
    "token": "nn23",
    "startOffset": 34,
    "endOffset": 36,
    "position": 7
    },
    {
    "token": "12mm",
    "startOffset": 37,
    "endOffset": 41,
    "position": 8
    },
    {
    "token": "thread",
    "startOffset": 44,
    "endOffset": 50,
    "position": 9
    },
    {
    "token": "length",
    "startOffset": 51,
    "endOffset": 57,
    "position": 10
    },
    {
    "token": "14mm",
    "startOffset": 58,
    "endOffset": 62,
    "position": 11
    }
]
}
```

Which would be returned for people searching for 12mm wheel bolts.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The Microsoft English Analyzer will treat decimal as a delimiter and generate 2 separate tokens.

If you want to perform exact match on few fields( eg: search for "M12-1.50 Wheel Bolt - 14mm. Hex, 23.12mm"), then I would suggest using the use "keyword" analyzer with lowercase tokenizer.

You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search